# consulta UPDATE aveces falla MYSQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes tengo un problema al descontar un numero de mi tabla, es decir mayormente resta bien pero existen ocaciones en las que la resta no se da.

mi tabla es la siguiente:
productos:

```
-------------------
|id_producto|unidades|
-------------------
|     100   |   100  |
|     200   |   20   |
----------------------
```

mi conexion a mi base de datos mysql desde php:

```
$bd = new mysqli("localhost","host","clave","basededatos");
$bd->set_charset("utf8");
```

y mi consulta a la base de datos es:

```
$unidades_descontar = 10;
$id_producto = 100;
$bd->query("update productos set unidades=unidades-".$unidades_descontar." where id_producto=".$id_producto);

$unidades_descontar = 20;
$id_producto = 100;
$bd->query("update productos set unidades=unidades-".$unidades_descontar." where id_producto=".$id_producto);

$unidades_descontar = 10;
$id_producto = 200;
$bd->query("update productos set unidades=unidades-".$unidades_descontar." where id_producto=".$id_producto);
```

Yo lo e probado y mayormente todo funciona correcto, pero existen ocaciones en las que no se descuenta el stock y yo valido y verifico las variables `$id_producto` & variable `$unidades_descontar`.
Notas:

- Esto solo es un ejemplo pero en realidad yo recorro un foreach y en cada ciclo ejecuto el update pero esto es basicamente lo mismo
- Esta funcion varias veces es ejecutada por 2 o 3 usuarios al mismo tiempo ( aunque esto paresca ser lo que genera el error son muy pocas veces las que un usuario interactual al mismo segudo que otro)

Comment: Es mejor resolver esto mediante un TRIGGER programado en la base de datos. Imaginemos que el producto se vende o un contexto parecido, en la tabla que controla las ventas, disparas el TRIGGER, para que descuente del stock las unidades que se hayan vendido cada vez... Los TRIGGER existen para eso, y no deberías tirarle a PHP problemas que corresponden a la BD, pues pasan cosas como estas y puede ir a peor, por ejemplo, si las conexiones concurrentes van en aumento.

Comment: @A.Cedano buen consejo amigo, si tuvieras un ejemplo me ayudaria bastante, de todas maneras investigare esto

Comment: [Lee sobre `TRIGGER` e intenta programar uno](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/), recuerda que los mismos se programan en el SGBD, no en PHP. Si no te funciona puedes abrir una pregunta y mostrarnos lo que tengas escrito. La tabla que dispararía el TRIGGER sería aquella que confirma la venta digamos. Cuando ya se ha confirmado que ese producto fue comprado, descontarías la cantidad comprada de la otra tabla, la que controla la totalidad de productos existentes. Imagino un contexto de compra y venta, pero puede ser otro, es sólo un ejemplo.

Comment: Esto es claramente un problema de concurrencia. Deberias leer sobre transacciones tambien (y siempre tomar en cuenta que todos los usuarios apretan el boton al mismo tiempo). Todo lo que te comento Cedano es totalmente correcto...

Comment: muchas gracias por sus comentarios me sirvieron ahora si a investigar

Comment: @A.Cedano ya lei todo y me va super bien para mis productos pero que pasaria cuando tengo un combo de productos es decir un producto que contenga otros productos, alli como aplicaria los trigger si yo almacenos en una columna "sub-productos" este string id_producto:cantidad;id_producto:cantidad

Comment: Pues lo que pasa ahí es que tienes un **error de diseño**. Cuando hablas de que guardas valores como cadenas, no hay duda de que debes repensar la forma en que tienes organizados tus datos. Una de las características principales de las BD es que son **relacionales**, eso se rompe si tú, por aparente comodidad o pensando que es mejor, decides guardar varias filas en una columna (valores separados por coma). Tarde o temprano eso dará problemas, por ejemplo, si necesitas filtrar usando como criterio alguna de esas columnas que tienes juntas, o si decides ordenar, o calcular algo, etc.